# How to handle a dual-boot system after recompiling a kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, gentoo

I have a dual-boot system, on /dev/sdb4 I have Gentoo, and on /dev/sdb5 I installed Ubuntu 18.04 afterwards. My boot partition is /dev/sdb2, and I let Ubuntu handle the whole bootloader stuff. And that worked well, Ubuntu found my Gentoo installation, added it to Grub, and I was able to boot into both operating systems.

Now I updated the Kernel within Gentoo, recompiled it and `emerge --depclean`ed, so the old Kernel is gone now. Didn't think much about it.

But now I can't boot into Gentoo anymore. There's still a Grub entry for it, but it doesn't work, so Grub boots into Ubuntu nonetheless. I've tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` again, and also `update-grub` from within Ubuntu. It still says that it finds the Gentoo installation, and there is still a Grub entry for it, but it is not bootable.

I have mounted both Gentoo's and Ubuntu's /boot directory to /dev/sdb2, but let Ubuntu clean it in its own installation, so I fear that Gentoo's /boot directory points to the partition that Ubuntu has erased and created anew.

I'm still on a BIOS-system, by the way. No UEFI yet.

How can I repair this mess without having to go through reinstalling kind of everything?

Comment: For start show us the content of `grub.cfg`. `fstab` can be helpful too. gentoo doesn't delete old kernel with `emerge --depcleaan`, just removes its sources. If you compiled new kernel then most probably all all you need to do is copy new image to `/boot/` and update grub config. You can do all these stuff from within ubuntu.

Comment: @jimmij: Thank you very much. Indeed I just had to do `make install` on the gentoo kernel to get it to the `/boot` partition and then  `grub-mkconfig` in Ubuntu. However, I had to delete the `grub.cfg` file before as `grub-mkconfig` doesn't seem to overwrite it, if present. Now I have a functional dual-boot system again. Thank you. :)